# Php closure without use keyword

Tags: php

```
$bar =function foo() use (&a) {

};

function bar(&b) {

}
```

what's different when php closure without use keyword?

for use, do I must use anonymous function? why? (I got error if I don't store inside of variable)

Comment: I use an anonymous function if I need a function that I will only used once or will only be used inside one specific piece of script. The closure I would use as the answer is suggesting below. I usually would pass the current class or some other element I may require inside the function. I personally don't use anon functions very often but they come in handy every once and awhile.

Answer (score 0):

use keyword used whenever your closure want to access variable outside the closure.

```
$a = "some value";

$bar = function() use($a) {
    $a = "other value";
};

$bar();
print($a);
// Result: other value
```

Comment: 1. why need tto use anonymous? 2. without use, it still can access & update outside variable

Comment: by the way, your use(&$a) u forgot &

Comment: @BenjaminW Use of `&` is for passing be reference, it's not required unless u need it.

Comment: hadi type // Result: other value at the end, so i believe he wants to passing by reference not value

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, the result is modifying the original so yeah it would have to pass by ref in this instance. My mistake.